# Concatenate XMLHTTPRequest responses within a loop to log when all loops are complete

Tags: javascript

`json.orderItem.length == 2`, So 2 `HTTP` requests are fired.
If I fire these 2 requests one after another (not in a loop), I receive these 2 separate responses:

1 'productName1, partNumber2342'

2 'productName2, partNumber8789'

I would like to concatenate these responses as they return so, at some point, I can log all of the responses as a single string.
How could I achieve this?

At the moment I've no way of identifying if all requests have completed and therefore log the final `String`.

Requests wrapped in a loop ..

```
var f = (function(){
    var xhr = [];
    var test = '';
    for (i = 0; i < json.orderItem.length; i++){
        (function (i){
            xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
            url = '/products/byId/' + json.orderItem[i].productId;
            xhr[i].open("GET", url, true);
            xhr[i].onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr[i].readyState == 4 && xhr[i].status == 200) {
                    test += JSON.parse(xhr[i].responseText).entry[0].name + ', ' + JSON.parse(xhr[i].responseText).entry[0].partNumber;
                }
            };
            xhr[i].send();
        })(i);
    }
})();
```

Comment: This would have to be done Asynchronously. You can't just loop over AJAX calls, because success may happen after the loop has already completed. Use a higher level scoped variable to concatenate to, upon the success of each AJAX call.

Comment: @PHPglue I believe `test` is the variable your referring to? How can I perform an `alert(test)` when all `XMLHTTPRequests` are finished?

Comment: `test` will only be what you want it to be when `status === 200 && readyStaty === 4`, so it won't just be available in other code outside of `onreadystatechange`. Also, your second AJAX request needs to happen inside of the other one, `onreadystatechange`, or there is no way to know if the data added to your `test` variable is not `''`.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't get all the relevant records with just on XHR call? XHR calls are expensive as in time to send, process server-side and return the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript closures:

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables. In other words, the function defined in the closure 'remembers' the environment in which it was created.

taken from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Closures are an extremely powerful concept in Javascript so I suggest you go read up on it if you aren't familiar with them.

Now how can we use this to solve your problem?

```
var f = (function() {
    // scope a
    var xhr = [],
        successfulRequests = 0,
        responseString = "";

    for (i = 0; i < json.orderItem.length; i++){
        (function (i) {
            xhr[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
            url = '/products/byId/' + json.orderItem[i].productId;
            xhr[i].open("GET", url, true);
            xhr[i].onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr[i].readyState == 4 && xhr[i].status == 200) {
                    // scope b

                    // track successful requests here
                    successfulRequests++;                   // "remembered" through closure
                    responseString += xhr[i].responseText;  // "remembered" through closure

                    if(successfulRequests == json.orderItem.length) {
                        console.log(responseString);
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr[i].send();
        })(i);
    }
})();
```

The variables declared in scopeA are remembered in scopeB via closure.

Note: This implementation will only log the responseString after ALL requests successfully complete. How you want to handle request failures is up to you but hopefully you should know how to do it now.

Comment: Very thorough response. This saved me a lot of time! Thanks Nikhil.

Answer (score 0):

name your action and use a common location to store results, and a callback for when everything is done; alert() is used in this simple example:

```
var test = '';
function grab(i, done){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = '/products/byId/' + json.orderItem[i].productId;
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.onload= function () {
                var ob=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                test += ob.entry[0].name + ', ' +ob.entry[0].partNumber;
                if(json.orderItem[i+1]){ //more items, pass forward:
                      grab(i+1, done); 
                }else{ //no more, run run done()
                      done(test);
                }
        };
        xhr.send();
}//end grab
grab(0, alert);
```

you might want to abstract it more to pass in a collection or results list to make it more re-usable, but the same basic step sequence can be used to keep order in async operations.

you could get fancier and dispatch them all at once and order them as they come in, but that's a bit more advanced. look into Promises to make stuff like that relatively easy.